# KNeighborsClassifier: Can I specify number of leafs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parameters, knn

By using KNeighborsClassifier,I predict the categories and the number of categories predicted is not so homogeneneos.Let's say I got 3 categories and 100 samples, KNN will predict this samples category 0 or category 1 or category 2. The problem is KNN predicts category 0=40 samples, category 1=50 samples and category 2=10 samples; what I want is this number of predicted categories never be smaller than 20. So category 2 must be at least 20. I look the leaf size but It is something different. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Set the `k` value in your classifier?

Comment: Yes,i set the k.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the idea of KNeighborsClassifier.

In KNeighborsClassifier you have the following parameters:

```
   n_neighbors
   weights
   algorithm
   leaf_size
   p
   metric
   metric_params
  n_jobs
```

you can find the full description [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html?highlight=kneighborsclassifier#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier). the life size:
Leaf size passed to BallTree or KDTree. This can affect the speed of the construction and query, as well as the memory required to store the tree. The optimal value depends on the nature of the problem.

doesnt help you in that case, because it just gives an indication how many trees the algorithm use for calculate the points. None of the others parameters help you either. The KNN works that it will find the nearest neighbors and you cannot adjust a minimum number in each class, you can only try to fit the all of the parameters that it fits for the best case for you.

Comment: Ok,then can i see the propabilities of categories?Like sample1=%60 prob category 1, %30 prob category 2 etc.